# How to build Node.JS Mobile backend on google cloud

Tags: python, node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

So I have been researching this for quite sometime. After reviewing the documentation and watching YouTube videos I still have had a hard time understanding how this process goes.

I am building a mobile application that will run on iOS and Android. I need to develop a backend for this application and have decided to use Node.JS , and potentially Python for a portion of it, and to host it on the Google Cloud Platform. How would I get this setup? I've gone through the Cloud Endpoints documentation but I am so confused. What I'm trying to do is have it set up so that I can develop locally, and deploy it to a test backend, and then migrate my work to a production backend once I have verified it is working in both dev/test environments.

That being said, I think my question is how would I go about simply just setting up a NodeJS mobile backend on Google Cloud?

Comment: There are countless tutorials for this. Start here and get your local development environment setup: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/setup Once that is complete and you understand how to develop locally, look at other tutorials: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/tutorials/bookshelf-on-compute-engine

Comment: Node and/or Python. Pick one or the other. Until you really understand how to deploy client / backend systems... Either language will do everything you want. I recommend Node as you will need to write in JavaScript for the client side, might as well use JavaScript for the backend too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cloud Endpoints Frameworks doesn’t support Node.js, [only Python 2.7 and Java 8](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks#limitations).

This is what the [Endpoints Frameworks](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks) does:

> Like other web frameworks, Endpoints Frameworks handles the low-level
>   communication details of HTTP requests and responses for your
>   application. When a client sends a request to your API, Endpoints
>   Frameworks routes the request's URL to the function or method in your
>   code that processes the request. Endpoints Frameworks converts the
>   return value to JSON and sends the response. You add metadata (by
>   using annotations in Java and decorators in Python) to your source
>   code. The metadata defines the surface of the REST APIs for your
>   application.

So, all you need to do is to create a service with [App Engine standard with Java or Python](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-app-backend-services#appengine-endpoints)

If you still want to use Node.js for your backend, [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-app-backend-services#matrix) you can see other options you can use